# jQuery and JavaScript issue with MCQ question format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code for MCQ questions. The functionality is when I click on  'insert new' in question section it shows a question  and an input field with its options. We can create multiple questions.

But my problem is when I click on add more option button it will add option on first question tab but when I create new question without closing the first Question and then click on add new option button of first question then it add option on newest adding question.

I want if I click on add more option button it will add option on same question.

**How to reproduce the issue?**

First add new question and don't close the question, then click on 'insert new' button and then click on add more option button of first question then you can see the problem. Please resize the window if you [open it in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajanchopra21/rvsj0yfw/10/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  var q = 4;

  $('#insertnewqstnbtn').click(function() {
    i++;
    $('#newqstndiv').append('<div id="appenddiv' + i + '" class="ms-create-new-form"><h2 class= "ms-font-xl"> Add New Question <span><a href="javascript:;" id="' + i + '" class="closebtn"><a/></span></h2><div class="multichoice-question-btn"><div class="item"><span>Multiple Choice?</span><input type = "checkbox" id = "toggleaddqstn_' + i + '"><div class= "toggle"><label for="toggleaddqstn_' + i + '"><i></i></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-input-field-div"><input id="questiontxt' + i + '" type="text" placeholder="Enter question text here" class="ms-title-field question" /></div><div class="ms-form-first-group form-for-ans"><div class="ms-ans-text"><p>Answer</p></div><div class="ms-correct-text"><p>Correct?</p></div></div><div class="border-bottom-line-ans"></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field' + i + '1"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option 1 text" id="option1' + i + '" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="checkboxn1' + i + '" name="checboxname' + i + '" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn1' + i + '"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field' + i + '2"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option 2 text" id="option2' + i + '" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="checkboxn2' + i + '" name="checboxname' + i + '" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn2' + i + '"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field' + i + '3"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option 3 text" id="option3' + i + '" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="checkboxn3' + i + '" name="checboxname' + i + '" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn3' + i + '"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field' + i + '4"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option 4 text" id="option4' + i + '" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" name="checboxname' + i + '" id="checkboxn4' + i + '" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn4' + i + '"></label></div></div></div><span class="add-filed"><a href="javascript:;" id="add-field_' + i + '"></a></span><div class="ms-pagin-div" id="rqdoptionsdiv"><div class="ms-pagin-text"><p>Required correct answer</p></div><div class="ms-pagin-num" id="correctOptNum"><span>2</span><span>3</span><span class="active">4</span></div></div><button id="addnewqstnCancelbtn" class="newcoursecancelbtn">Cancel</button><button id="addnewqstnbtn_' + i + '" class="ms-cm-button add-detail-btn createquestion" style="width:40%;">Create</button><label id="chkpointErrMsg"></label><div class="border-bottom-line mb-bottom-15"></div></div>');

    var checkMultiChoice = $("#toggleaddqstn_" + i);
    var addMoreBtn = $("#add-field_" + i);

    addMoreBtn.click(function() {
      var parentDiv = "#appenddiv" + i;
      var lastDiv = ".ms-form-second-ground:last";

      var addFieldSplit = $(this).attr('id');
      var fieldSplit = addFieldSplit.split('_');
      var fieldSplitFirst = fieldSplit[0];
      var fieldSplitTwo = fieldSplit[1];
      q++;
      if (checkMultiChoice.prop("checked") == true) {
        $(parentDiv + " " + ".ms-form-second-ground:last").after('<div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field' + i + '' + q + '"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option ' + q + ' text" id="option' + q + '' + i + '" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="checkbox" name="checboxname' + i + '" id="checkboxn' + q + '' + i + '" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn' + q + '' + i + '"></label></div></div></div>');
      } else if (checkMultiChoice.prop("checked") == false) {
        $('<div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field' + i + '' + q + '"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option ' + q + ' text" id="option' + q + '' + i + '" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" name="checboxnamee' + i + '" id="checkboxn' + q + '' + i + '" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn' + q + '' + i + '"></label></div></div></div>').insertAfter(parentDiv + " " + ".ms-form-second-ground:last");
      }
    });
    var splitCheck = (checkMultiChoice.attr('id')).split("_");
    var splicheckfirst = splitCheck[0];
    var splichecksecond = splitCheck[1];

    checkMultiChoice.click(function() {
      if ((checkMultiChoice).prop("checked") == true) {

        for (var input = 1; input <= q; input++) {
          var btnOption = "checkboxn" + input + splichecksecond;

          $("#" + btnOption).attr('type', 'checkbox');
        }
      } else if ((checkMultiChoice).prop("checked") == false) {
        for (var input = 1; input <= q; input++) {
          var btnOption = "checkboxn" + input + splichecksecond;
          $("#" + btnOption).attr('type', 'radio');
        }

      }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.closebtn', function() {
      var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
      $('#appenddiv' + button_id + '').remove();
    });

    //var questionAdd = 0;
    $('.createquestion').click(function() {
      //questionAdd++;
      var id = this.id;
      var split_id = id.split('_');
      var text = split_id[0];
      var bid = split_id[1];
      var questionId = $("#questiontxt" + bid).val();
      var ansFirst = $("#option1" + bid).val();
      var ansSecond = $("#option2" + bid).val();
      var ansThird = $("#option3" + bid).val();
      var ansFourth = $("#option4" + bid).val();
      $('#main-after-append').append('<div class="after-append" id="afterappendid' + i + '"><div class="d-flex-questions"><div class="m-question-2"><h3 class="ms-font-xl" id="qstnumber' + i + '">Question ' + i + '</h3><span>(Locate after page 1)</span></div><div class="multichoice-question-btn"><form  style="width:100%;" class="ms-second-form"><div class="item"><span>Multiple Choice?</span><input type="checkbox" id="toggle_today_summary2" name="" value=""><div class="toggle"><label for="toggle_today_summary2"><i></i></label></div></div></form></div></div><h4 class="ms-font-xl"><input type="text" id="question' + i + '" value="' + questionId + '" class="question-a"></h4><form  class="form-for-ans"><div class="ms-form-first-group"><div class="ms-ans-text"><p>Answer</p></div><div class="ms-correct-text"><p>Correct?</p></div></div><div class="border-bottom-line-ans"></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" value="' + ansFirst + '" id="ans' + i + '"/></div><div class="ms-check-icon"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="radio" name="ans" value="everyone" /><label for="radio"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" value="' + ansSecond + '" id="ans' + i + '"/></div><div class="ms-check-icon"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="ans" value="Not me" /><label for="radio2"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" value="' + ansThird + '" id="ans' + i + '"/></div><div class="ms-check-icon"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="radio3" name="ans" value="My Manager" /><label for="radio3"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" value="' + ansFourth + '" id="ans' + i + '"/></div><div class="ms-check-icon"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="radio4" name="ans" value="My Manager" /><label for="radio4"></label></div></div></div></form></div><div class="border-bottom-line mb-bottom-15"></div></div>');
      $("#appenddiv" + i).hide();
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newqstndiv"></div>
<button id="insertnewqstnbtn" class="ms-cm-button"> Insert New</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at your code. The problem is that you are using the var i in your on click event (addMoreBtn.click) so it always referring to the latest question created. You need a way to track what question the event handler applies to.

One way to do this is to add a data attribute to the anchor tag (#appenddiv+i). I added a data attribute (data-num) in the code snippet below I also updated the click event to use the data attribute instead of i.

I have added comments as well to highlight the changes. See snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  var q = 4;

  $('#insertnewqstnbtn').click(function() {
    i++;

    // <a href="javascript:;" id="add-field_'+i+'" data-num="'+i+'"></a> added data-num attribute
    $('#newqstndiv').append('<div id="appenddiv' + i + '" class="ms-create-new-form"><h2 class= "ms-font-xl"> Add New Question <span><a href="javascript:;" id="' + i + '" class="closebtn"><a/></span></h2><div class="multichoice-question-btn"><div class="item"><span>Multiple Choice?</span><input type = "checkbox" id = "toggleaddqstn_' + i + '"><div class= "toggle"><label for="toggleaddqstn_' + i + '"><i></i></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-input-field-div"><input id="questiontxt' + i + '" type="text" placeholder="Enter question text here" class="ms-title-field question" /></div><div class="ms-form-first-group form-for-ans"><div class="ms-ans-text"><p>Answer</p></div><div class="ms-correct-text"><p>Correct?</p></div></div><div class="border-bottom-line-ans"></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field' + i + '1"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option 1 text" id="option1' + i + '" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="checkboxn1' + i + '" name="checboxname' + i + '" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn1' + i + '"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field' + i + '2"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option 2 text" id="option2' + i + '" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="checkboxn2' + i + '" name="checboxname' + i + '" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn2' + i + '"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field' + i + '3"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option 3 text" id="option3' + i + '" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="checkboxn3' + i + '" name="checboxname' + i + '" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn3' + i + '"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field' + i + '4"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option 4 text" id="option4' + i + '" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" name="checboxname' + i + '" id="checkboxn4' + i + '" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn4' + i + '"></label></div></div></div><span class="add-filed"><a href="javascript:;" id="add-field_' + i + '" data-num="' + i + '"></a></span><div class="ms-pagin-div" id="rqdoptionsdiv"><div class="ms-pagin-text"><p>Required correct answer</p></div><div class="ms-pagin-num" id="correctOptNum"><span>2</span><span>3</span><span class="active">4</span></div></div><button id="addnewqstnCancelbtn" class="newcoursecancelbtn">Cancel</button><button id="addnewqstnbtn_' + i + '" class="ms-cm-button add-detail-btn createquestion" style="width:40%;">Create</button><label id="chkpointErrMsg"></label><div class="border-bottom-line mb-bottom-15"></div></div>');

    var checkMultiChoice = $("#toggleaddqstn_" + i);
    var addMoreBtn = $("#add-field_" + i);

    addMoreBtn.click(function() {




      // changed  var parentDiv = "#appenddiv" + i;
      //to:
      var parentDiv = "#appenddiv" + $(this).data("num");
      var lastDiv = ".ms-form-second-ground:last";
      // added r to count how many fields are in this question
      var r = $(parentDiv + ' > [id^=option]').length+1 ;
      var addFieldSplit = $(this).attr('id');
      var fieldSplit = addFieldSplit.split('_');
      var fieldSplitFirst = fieldSplit[0];
      var fieldSplitTwo = fieldSplit[1];
      q++;
      if (checkMultiChoice.prop("checked") == true) {
        $(parentDiv + ".ms-form-second-ground:last").after('<div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field' + i + '' + r + '"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option ' + r + ' text" id="option' + r + '' + i + '" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="checkbox" name="checboxname' + i + '" id="checkboxn' + r + '' + i + '" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn' + r + '' + i + '"></label></div></div></div>');
      } else if (checkMultiChoice.prop("checked") == false) {
        $('<div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field' + i + '' + r + '"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option ' + r + ' text" id="option' + r + '' + i + '" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" name="checboxnamee' + i + '" id="checkboxn' + r + '' + i + '" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn' + r + '' + i + '"></label></div></div></div>').insertAfter(parentDiv + " " + ".ms-form-second-ground:last");
      }
    });
    var splitCheck = (checkMultiChoice.attr('id')).split("_");
    var splicheckfirst = splitCheck[0];
    var splichecksecond = splitCheck[1];

    checkMultiChoice.click(function() {
      if ((checkMultiChoice).prop("checked") == true) {

        for (var input = 1; input <= q; input++) {
          var btnOption = "checkboxn" + input + splichecksecond;

          $("#" + btnOption).attr('type', 'checkbox');
        }
      } else if ((checkMultiChoice).prop("checked") == false) {
        for (var input = 1; input <= q; input++) {
          var btnOption = "checkboxn" + input + splichecksecond;
          $("#" + btnOption).attr('type', 'radio');
        }

      }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.closebtn', function() {
      var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
      $('#appenddiv' + button_id + '').remove();
    });

    //var questionAdd = 0;
    $('.createquestion').click(function() {
      //questionAdd++;
      var id = this.id;
      var split_id = id.split('_');
      var text = split_id[0];
      var bid = split_id[1];
      var questionId = $("#questiontxt" + bid).val();
      var ansFirst = $("#option1" + bid).val();
      var ansSecond = $("#option2" + bid).val();
      var ansThird = $("#option3" + bid).val();
      var ansFourth = $("#option4" + bid).val();
      $('#main-after-append').append('<div class="after-append" id="afterappendid' + i + '"><div class="d-flex-questions"><div class="m-question-2"><h3 class="ms-font-xl" id="qstnumber' + i + '">Question ' + i + '</h3><span>(Locate after page 1)</span></div><div class="multichoice-question-btn"><form  style="width:100%;" class="ms-second-form"><div class="item"><span>Multiple Choice?</span><input type="checkbox" id="toggle_today_summary2" name="" value=""><div class="toggle"><label for="toggle_today_summary2"><i></i></label></div></div></form></div></div><h4 class="ms-font-xl"><input type="text" id="question' + i + '" value="' + questionId + '" class="question-a"></h4><form  class="form-for-ans"><div class="ms-form-first-group"><div class="ms-ans-text"><p>Answer</p></div><div class="ms-correct-text"><p>Correct?</p></div></div><div class="border-bottom-line-ans"></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" value="' + ansFirst + '" id="ans' + i + '"/></div><div class="ms-check-icon"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="radio" name="ans" value="everyone" /><label for="radio"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" value="' + ansSecond + '" id="ans' + i + '"/></div><div class="ms-check-icon"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="ans" value="Not me" /><label for="radio2"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" value="' + ansThird + '" id="ans' + i + '"/></div><div class="ms-check-icon"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="radio3" name="ans" value="My Manager" /><label for="radio3"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" value="' + ansFourth + '" id="ans' + i + '"/></div><div class="ms-check-icon"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="radio4" name="ans" value="My Manager" /><label for="radio4"></label></div></div></div></form></div><div class="border-bottom-line mb-bottom-15"></div></div>');
      $("#appenddiv" + i).hide();
    });

  });
});
```

```css
/* Page-specific styling */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa&display=swap');
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0 0 0px;
  /* bottom = footer height */
  /** margin:0 0 40px;*/
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}


/*.padding {*/


/*    padding: 15px;*/


/*}*/

#notification-popup.ms-MessageBanner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  height: inherit;
  min-width: inherit;
}

#notification-popup .ms-MessageBanner-text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 18px 15px;
  min-width: inherit;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ms-no-padding {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.ms-welcome__header {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  -webkit-justify-content: left;
}

.ms-welcome__main {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: left;
  -webkit-align-items: left;
}

.ms-welcome__main>h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.ms-welcome__features {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.ms-welcome__features.ms-List .ms-ListItem {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.ms-welcome__features.ms-List .ms-ListItem>.ms-Icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.ms-welcome__action.ms-Button--hero {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.ms-Button.ms-Button--hero .ms-Button-label {
  color: #0078d7;
}

.ms-create-new-form .ms-Button.ms-Button--hero:hover .ms-Button-label,
.ms-Button.ms-Button--hero:focus .ms-Button-label {
  color: #005a9e;
  cursor: pointer;
}

b {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/** custom css **/

.ms-welcome__header h2,
.ms-section-first h2,
.ms-section-second h2,
.ms-section-sixth h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 20px 0px 5px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}

.ms-create-new-form h2,
.ms-section-fourth h2,
.ms-section-fifth h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}

.ms-create-new-form h2 {
  position: relative;
}

.ms-section-fifth.mt-20 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.ms-section-fifth .m-question-2 h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.ms-section-fifth h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.ms-section-fifth .m-question-2 span {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.ms-section-first,
.ms-section-second,
.ms-section-third,
.ms-section-fourth,
.ms-section-fifth,
.ms-section-sixth,
.ms-section-seventh {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}


/**.ms-section-first, .ms-section-third, .ms-section-fifth, .ms-section-seventh {
    background-color: #fff9fa;
}
    */

.ms-select-filed {
  border-top: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #fff9fa;
}

.d-flex-btn {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.ms-section-first>p {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-family: inherit;
  float: left;
}

.ms-cm-button {
  width: 50%;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #039be5;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}

.ms-cm-button-update {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #039be5;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}

.newcoursecancelbtn {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 10px 0px 20px 0px;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}

.ms-table-first {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #dadbdc;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100%;
}

.ms-table-first th {
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

.ms-table-first tr td {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.ms-table-first tr td button {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.form-for-ans {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}


/** toogle css **/

.d-flex-questions {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.item span {
  margin: 0 0 0 0px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-right: 55px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.item input[type="checkbox"] {
  font-size: 0px !important;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}


/**input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
    */

.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 51px;
  height: 25px;
}

.toggle label,
.toggle i {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  background: #fff9fa;
}

.toggle label {
  width: 51px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  transition: all 0.30s ease;
  -webkit-transform: all 0.30s ease;
  -ms-transform: all 0.30s ease;
}

.toggle i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.275, -0.450, 0.725, 1.450);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 cubic-bezier(0.0275, 0.725, 0.450)
}

input[type="checkbox"]:active+.toggle i {
  width: 35px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:active+.toggle label,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.toggle label {
  background-color: #039be5;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.toggle i {
  left: 26px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:active+.toggle label {
  border: 16px solid #e5e5e5;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:active+.toggle i {
  left: 14px;
}

.ms-form-first-group {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
}

.ms-form-first-group p {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000;
}

.ms-form-second-ground {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%
}

.ms-form-second-ground>.ms-ans-text-2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ms-form-second-ground>.ms-ans-text-2 input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #dadbdc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 400;
}


/** round icons **/

.round {
  position: relative;
}

.round input[type="radio"]+label {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 28px;
  left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10% !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 28px;
  left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
}

.round label:after {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  content: "";
  height: 6px;
  left: 7px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 12px;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #039be5;
  border-color: #66bb6a;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.round input[type="radio"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.round input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #039be5;
  border-color: #66bb6a;
}

.round input[type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.ms-pagin-div {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.ms-pagin-div p {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.ms-pagin-div span:first-child,
.ms-pagin-div span:last-child {
  border: 1px solid #039be5;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #039be5;
}

.ms-pagin-div span.active {
  background-color: #039be5;
  color: #fff;
}

.ms-only-line {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.ms-section-seventh {
  padding: 0px 15px;
}


/** select css **/

.ms-dropdown {
  border: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #dadbdc;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.ms-dropdown:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/** custom css for signin*/

#login-msg .s-font-x {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 23px;
}

#login-msg #sign-in {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.tg-s-txt {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.tg-s-txt p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tg-s-txt,
.tg-s-txt p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 5px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.sign-out-btn {
  background-color: #005a9e;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px 4px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/** modal csss */

.m-all {
  color: #000;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.f-group-f input,
.f-group-s input {
  display: block;
  width: 96%;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}

.f-group-f,
.f-group-s {
  margin: 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.f-group-f .label,
.f-group-s .label {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.f-group-f input,
.f-group-s input {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #dadbdc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#loginButton {
  background-color: #005a9e;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  border: 0px solid #005a9e;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #005a9e;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.s-acc {
  background-color: #005a9e;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.s-acc h2 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.login-google,
#googleButton {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.btn-s-g {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.btn-s-g p {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#googleButton span {
  color: #000;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.d-flex img {
  width: 22px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#googleButton,
.login-google,
.btn-s-g {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}


/** add course details css */

.ms-input-field-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.add-detail-btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.ms-input-field-div label {
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.ms-input-field-div input,
.ms-input-field-div textarea,
.ms-input-field-div select {
  width: 60%;
}

.ms-input-field-div input,
.ms-input-field-div textarea {
  border: 1px solid #dadbdc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.w-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 15px !important;
}

.w-checkbox {
  justify-content: flex-start !important;
}

.w-checkbox label {
  width: 15px !important;
}

.ms-input-field-div input {
  height: 25px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.ms-create-new-form {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0.5px #33333314;
  padding: 8px 20px 0px 20px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.mycheckbox {
  display: block !important;
  width: 15px !important;
  height: 15px !important;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  color: #ee4a42;
}

.border-bottom-line {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #dadbdc;
  width: 100%;
}

.border-bottom-line-ans {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #dadbdc;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.question-with-ans input {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #dadbdc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.question-with-ans input::placeholder {
  color: #828482;
}

.mb-bottom-15 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}


/** close button css **/

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.closebtn:before,
.closebtn:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 15px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.closebtn:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.closebtn:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


/** add button **/

.add-filed {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.add-filed a {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #039be5;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.add-filed a:before,
.add-filed a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 10px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.add-filed a:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.question-a {
  border: 0px solid #fff0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content-main" class="ms-welcome__main" style="width: 25%;">
  <!--  style="display: none;" -->
  <div class="padding">

    <!--add new question-->
    <div class="ms-section-fifth" id="main-after-append"></div>
    <div id="newqstndiv"></div>

    <button id="insertnewqstnbtn" class="ms-cm-button"> Insert New</button>

    <div class="ms-section-sixth">
      <h2 class="ms-font-xl">Update Courses</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-section-seventh">
      <button class="ms-cm-button-update"> Update Course</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```